# setState not updating object state in functional component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am a bit new in react native and I have got into an interesting situation.
I have a Login screen in which there are two fields;

1. Mobile number.
2. password

On Login button press I am executing two functions :

1. handleMobileInput() - which check if the mobile number is valid.
   2 handlePasswordInput() - which will check if password is valid.

I also have a global state named 'errors' initially it is empty object({}) and 'setErrors' function to update it. Full code looks like this

```
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const handleLogin = () => {
        handleMobileInput(mobileNo);
        handlePasswordInput(password);
        if (errors.mobError || errors.passError) {
            return;
        }
    }
    const handleMobileInput = (mobileNo) => {
        if (!mobileNo) {
            const x = { ...errors, mobError: 'mobile no. is required'}
            console.log(x); //outputs correctly
            setErrors(x);
            console.log(errors); //output incorrectly even when I click login again and again
        } else if (mobileNo.length !== 10) {
            setErrors({ ...errors, mobError: 'mobile no must be of 10 digits'});
        } else {
            setErrors({ ...errors, mobError: ''});
        }
        setMobileNo(mobileNo);
    }

    const handlePasswordInput = (password) => {
        if (!password) {
            setErrors({ ...errors, passError: 'password is required'})
        } else if (password.length < 5) {
            setErrors({ ...errors, passError: 'password must be 6 characters long'});
        } else {
            setErrors({ ...errors, passError: ''})
        }
        setPassword(password);
    }
```

Now when I click login , handleLogin() function executes and it first validates mobile Number
since mobile number is empty(because I haven't touched it, I presses Login directly), variable x inside handleMobileInput() updated as `{ mobError: 'mobile no is required }` which is correct. But when I try to set the variable x to my state, it doesn't update it and return empty object. But it does update password state correctly. Now my final state 'errors' looks like this

```
{
passError: 'password is required'
}
```

but I need it as

```
{
mobError: 'mobile no is required',
passError: 'pass is required'
}
```

No matter How many times I presses the login button this state remains same and state for mobError never gets updated.
All these functions are inside my main functional component.
Full code looks like this

```
import React  from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, CheckBox } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, Title, Divider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { default as globalStyles }  from '../globalStyles';
import { useState } from 'react';


const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const [mobileNo, setMobileNo] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleMobileInput = (mobileNo) => {
        if (!mobileNo) {
            const x = { ...errors, mobError: 'mobile no. is required'}
            console.log(x); //outputs correctly
            setErrors(x);
            console.log(errors); //output incorrectly even when I click login again and again
        } else if (mobileNo.length !== 10) {
            setErrors({ ...errors, mobError: 'mobile no must be of 10 digits'});
        } else {
            setErrors({ ...errors, mobError: ''});
        }
        setMobileNo(mobileNo);
    }

    const handlePasswordInput = (password) => {
        if (!password) {
            setErrors({ ...errors, passError: 'password is required'})
        } else if (password.length < 5) {
            setErrors({ ...errors, passError: 'password must be 6 characters long'});
        } else {
            setErrors({ ...errors, passError: ''})
        }
        setPassword(password);
    }

    const handleLogin = () => {
        handleMobileInput(mobileNo);
        handlePasswordInput(password);
        if (errors.mobError || errors.passError) {
            return;
        }
    }

    return (
        <View  style={globalStyles.viewStyle}>
            <Card style={globalStyles.cardStyle}>
              <Card.Content>
                <Title style={globalStyles.title}>Welcome to Mshur</Title>
                <Divider style={{...globalStyles.divider, ...globalStyles.bgColorPrimary}}></Divider>
              </Card.Content>
              <View style={globalStyles.inputView}>
                <AntDesign name="user" size={24} color="white" style={{...globalStyles.inputIconStyle, ...globalStyles.bgColorPrimary}}/>
                <TextInput 
                    style={globalStyles.inputStyle} 
                    placeholder="enter mobile number" 
                    placeholderTextColor="grey"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    onChange = {(e) => {
                        handleMobileInput(e.nativeEvent.text);
                    }}>
                </TextInput>
                
              </View>
              {
                    errors.mobError ? 
                        (<Text style={globalStyles.error}>{errors.mobError}</Text>)
                    : null

              }
              <View style={{...globalStyles.inputView, ...globalStyles.marginTop_1}}>
                <AntDesign name="lock" size={24} color="white" style={{...globalStyles.inputIconStyle, ...globalStyles.bgColorPrimary}}/>
                <TextInput 
                    style={globalStyles.inputStyle} 
                    placeholder="enter password" 
                    placeholderTextColor="grey"
                    onChange = {(e) => {
                        handlePasswordInput(e.nativeEvent.text);
                    }}
                    >
                </TextInput>
              </View>
              {
                    errors.passError ? 
                        (<Text style={globalStyles.error}>{errors.passError}</Text>)
                    : null

              }
              <View style={styles.loginHelp}>
                  <View style={globalStyles.checkboxContainer}>
                    <CheckBox value={true}></CheckBox>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 13}}>Remember me?</Text>
                  </View>

                  <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.TouchableOpacityStyle}>
                      <Text style={{color: 'grey'}}>Forgot Password</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <Button 
                style={{marginHorizontal: 15, ...globalStyles.bgColorPrimary, ...globalStyles.buttonStyle}} 
                mode="contained" 
                contentStyle = {{ height: 40 }} 
                onPress={() => handleLogin()}>
                Login 
              </Button>
              <Button 
                style={{marginHorizontal: 15, ...globalStyles.bgColorSeconday, ...globalStyles.marginTop_1, ...globalStyles.buttonStyle}} 
                mode="contained" 
                contentStyle = {{ height: 40 }} 
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
                New user? sign up 
              </Button>
            </Card>
        </View>
        
        
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    loginHelp: {
        display:'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginHorizontal: 15,
    },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setErrors` is asynchronous and would not show you updated state right away.

To check the update `errors` state you should log it inside a `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(errors) // will execute everytime errors change
},[errors])
```

To learn more you can check this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

**UPDATE**
In your case you are calling `handleMobileInput` and `handlePasswordInput` at the same time and both of them have `setErrors` which will update the state asynchronously and the problem that you are getting is happening because of race conditions.

So when you write `setErrors({ ...errors, passError: 'password is required'})` , at this time `errors` object doesn't have the updated `mobError` property and hence that property is always missing.

In order to overcome that I suggest that u don't call `setErrors` in both these functions but instead return a `error` string from them. and then call `setErrors` only once , in your `handleVote` method.
Please check the code below.

```
const handleMobileInput = (mobileNo) => {
   let mobileError;
  if (!mobileNo) {
    mobileError = 'mobile no. is required'
  } else if (mobileNo.length !== 10) {
    mobileError = 'mobile no must be of 10 digits';
  } else {
    mobileError = ''
     
  }
  setMobileNo(mobileNo);
  return mobileError;
}

const handlePasswordInput = (password) => {
  let passwordError;
  if (!password) {
    passwordError = 'password is required'
  } else if (password.length < 5) {
    passwordError = 'password is required'
  } else {
    passwordError = 'password is required'
  }
  setPassword(password);
  return passwordError;
}

const handleLogin = () => {
  const mobError = handleMobileInput(mobileNo);
  const passError = handlePasswordInput(password);
  setErrors({...errors,passError,mobError})
  if (mobError || passError) {
      return;
  }
}

useEffect(()=>{console.log(errors},[errors]) // will have updated fields
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think asynchronousity is the problem here, I have tried with ```await setState(errors)``` but the same issue, and the problem is not with console logging actually the error state never gets updated here. useEffect also didn't made any effect.

Comment: Actually `setState` is not a promise so adding `await` won't make any difference.It just update state asynchronously and when state gets updated the callback function in `useEffect` will get fired. Do you get anything in the console with `useEffect`?

Comment: Yes I got the object which I was previously getting (problem is not yet solved). The object I got is               ```                                                                                            { "passError": "password is required"}.                               ```

Comment: What I am expecting is ``` { "mobError": "mobile is required", passError: " password is required" }

Comment: Thanks for explanation. setState is very confusing

Answer (score 0):

`setState` works `async` way. As a result, you are not getting the updated value immediately.

You can use `useEffect` for that and pass the state as dependency, so every time `errors` state get change it would get invoke.

To achieve your goal use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
useEffect(() => console.log(errors), [errors])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think asynchronousity is the problem here, I have tried with ```await setState(errors)``` but the same issue, and the problem is not with console logging actually the error state never gets updated here. useEffect also didn't made any effect.